# Can I use this SSD on this motherboard

Tags: ssd, motherboard, port, storage, compatibility

Recently I bought a Western Digital SN570 1TB NVMe Solid State Drive. I currently have an ASUS P8B75-M motherboard which support my SATA SSD. However I am not sure if this SSD will go with my current motherboard.

I would appreciate it if someone could let me know if I can install this on my motherboard or not.

Comment: NVMe SSDs != SATA SSDs

Answer (score 2):

No, your mainboard does not have M.2 slots. Because it is so old, its firmware probably also does not support NVMe.

Next time, check before buying.

---

All is not lost however: Your mainboard has a PCI Express 2.0 x4 slot. If it is still unused, you could get an (inexpensive, ~$15) adapter card with an M.2 slot and use the SSD this way. Make sure the M.2 slot on the adapter card is keyed correctly: It needs to be M-keyed.

This way, you will get at least 50% of the SSD’s full performance.

You will not, however, be able to boot from the SSD.